# Error Exception Array to string conversion

Tags: php

acudo ante ustedes porque estoy tratando de hacer una comparación entre dos array y me arroja el siguiente error: ErrorException Array to string conversion.

estos son mis arrays

```
      Array 1:
      array:1 [▼
         0 => array:5 [▼
            0 => "11111111"
            1 => "22222222"
            2 => "33333333"
            3 => "44444444"
            4 => "65492969"
         ]
      ]

      Array 2

         array:2 [▼
             0 => array:8 [▼
              0 => "11111111"
              1 => "00000000"
              2 => "33338833"
              3 => "44444444"
              4 => "65492969"
              5 => "77777779"
              6 => "65492969"
              7 => "65498889"
              8 => "69999999"
            ]
         ]
```

Estoy es lo que he intentado sin éxito:

```
        $coincide = array_intersect($array1,$array2);

        $coincide = in_array($array1,$array2);
```

Mucho les agradecería si me pueden orientar para saber porque lanza el error, necesito compararlos y conocer los valores que coinciden y los que no coinciden, saludos y gracias por la ayuda que puedan brindarme

Comment: El primer parámetro de `in_array()` tiene que ser una cadena, no puedes pasarle un array. ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer con esto exactamente: `$coincide = in_array($array1,$array2);`?

Comment: comparar los dos para buscar coincidencias, luego guardar cada valor que coincide ejemplo 1111111,444444 y tambien necesito guardar las diferencias

Comment: Puedes recorrer `$array1` con un  `foreach` y verificar si cada valor del mismo se encuentra en `$array2`  y actuar en consecuencia ... o bien usar funciones más avanzadas. Sería más o menos así: `foreach ($array1 as $v) { if (in_array($v,$array2) { echo "$v existe en 2do array".PHP_EOL; } else { echo "$v no existe".PHP_EOL; } }` Sería cuestión de cambiar los `echo` por lo que quieras hacer.

Comment: gracias @A.Cedano ya no me sale el error pero como hago para imprimir los valores? porque echo "$v no existe" es el array 1 completo y yo quiero imprimir las coincidencias y diferencias

Comment: Prueba así: `foreach ($array1[0] as $v) { if (in_array($v,$array2[0]) { echo "$v existe en 2do array".PHP_EOL; } else { echo "$v no existe".PHP_EOL; } }` al parecer los arrays están anidados en un ìndice `0` en cada caso.

Comment: gracias @A.Cedano me puedes poner la respuesta para aceptarla por favor que fue perfecto, gracias por todo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes recorrer `$array1` con un `foreach` y verificar si cada valor del mismo se encuentra en `$array2` y actuar en consecuencia ... o bien usar funciones más avanzadas.

Al sacar cada valor dentro del `foreach` sí podrías usar `in_array()` sin problema.

Además, en la salida que compartes en la pregunta se ve que los arrays están anidados dentro de un sub-array que se encuentra en el índice `0`, lo cual debes reflejar en cada caso.

Sería algo así más o menos:

```
foreach ($array1[0] as $v) { 
    if (in_array($v,$array2[0]) { 
        #Aquí puedes hacer otra cosa, según convenga, lo mismo en el else
        echo "$v existe en 2do array".PHP_EOL; 
    } else { 
        echo "$v no existe".PHP_EOL; 
    } 
}
```

Sería cuestión de cambiar los echo por lo que quieras hacer.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que indicar el indice del array que quieres comparar, eso lo hace escribiendo los corchetes con el numero del indice a comparar.

```
    $coincide = array_intersect($array1[1],$array2[1]);

    $coincide = in_array($array1[1],$array2[1]);
```

Si quieres comparar todos los elementos, puedes usar un bucle for o foreach.